# How do I fix this argument error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently developing this battle game when all of a sudden I got this unexpected argument error. I might have done something wrong, but nothing I am able to see. So I would really appreciate it if someone could help me understand what is wrong.

game.py

```
import random

class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92n'
    WARNING = '\033[93n'
    FAIL = '\033[91n'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4n'

class Person:
    def _init_(self, hp, mp, atk, df, magic):
        self.maxhp = hp
        self.hp = hp
        self.maxmp = mp
        self.mp = mp
        self.atkl = atk - 10
        self.atkh = atk + 10
        self.df = df
        self.magic = magic
        self.actions = ["Attack", "Magic"]

    def generate_damage(self):
        return random.randrange(self.atkl, self.atkh)
```

main.py

```
from classes.game import Person, bcolors

magic = [{"name": "Fire", "cost": 10, "dmg": 60},
         {"name": "Thunder", "cost": 10, "dmg": 60},
         {"name": "Blizzard", "cost": 10, "dmg": 60}]


player = Person(460, 65, 60, 34, magic)

print(player.generate_damage())
print(player.generate_damage())
print(player.generate_damage())
```

The line of code with the warning message is in main.py and the line saids player = Person(460, 65, 60, 34, magic)
Thank you.

Comment: What's the error? Note: python's special functions are `__` double underscores.

Comment: all it saids is unexpected arguments

Answer (score 1):

You have to put two underscores `__` around your `init` statement. Your Person class should look like this:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, hp, mp, atk, df, magic):
        self.maxhp = hp
        self.hp = hp
        self.maxmp = mp
        self.mp = mp
        self.atkl = atk - 10
        self.atkh = atk + 10
        self.df = df
        self.magic = magic
        self.actions = ["Attack", "Magic"]

    def generate_damage(self):
        return random.randrange(self.atkl, self.atkh)
```